# Leaflet get the current style of a layer

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet javascript library i can't get the style value of a layer.
I have looked at the documentation but i can't see any way to do this!

Here how i set the style :

```
layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    opacity: 0.9,
});
```

There is a methode setStyle but not getStyle ... How can i check for those values?
I need this to know the state of a layer to know what to do if the layer is "red" etc ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`layer.options` contains those values.

Comment: This is true for the features in a layer, which are also called layer in leaflet. But for me the style for the layer containing the features is always undefined :(

Comment: ylka, that could be a scope issue. Are you using "this" and does it mean something different where you are?